# Different methods to make a null link?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

Is there a way to make a null link besides these methods?

```
<a href="javascript:;">Example</a>

<a href="javascript:void(0);">Example</a>

<a href="#">Example</a>
```

I don't mind something that makes the page jump to the top but I don't want it to alter the URL in the address bar. The ideal link would be one as similar as possible to [the ones featured on navigation boxes on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aNavbox#Parameter_list) but there is much more to that link than meets the eye as it has a pretty large script associated with it. I'm just looking for something to put into the `a` tag.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2nd option's your best bet for null behavior.

Comment: Yes, but it looks ugly in the status bar.

Comment: why does this need to be a link?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You just want something you can shove in the `<a>` tag? OK:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">Example</a>
```

Combine it with any of the `href=` methods from your question.

Given that a link that doesn't go anywhere is fairly useless, can I assume you want to kick off some JavaScript function when the link is clicked? If so, do this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="yourFunctionHere(); return false;">Example</a>
```

Comment: This is going to give you problems if you have a SPA application that relies on # links for routing navigation.

Answer (score 15):

The # method is the simplest, and is always compatible. Using a href=# however, will jump to the top of the page. To prevent the jump, simply reference an unnamed anchor. Like this:

```
<a href=#nothing >This link has a null href!</a>

<a href=#doesnotexist >This link has a null href!</a>

<a href=#null >This link has a null href!</a>

<a href=#void >This link has a null href!</a>

<a href=#whatever >This link has a null href!</a>
```

Comment: Or it will send you to mysite.com/#nothing

Answer (score 8):

No, all the *potentially valid* alternatives are not done IMO. I made the following experiments with Chrome and Firefox, managing to identify 2 extra alternatives to the ones already suggested in the question and the answers.

**The ones that failed (NOT null links):**

This one is not rendered as a link at all, and isn't clickable either.

```
<a>null-link-1</a>
```

The next alternative when clicked, moved to document start - *not a null link*.

```
<a href="">null-link-2</a>
```

The next alternative when clicked, navigates away from document - *not a null link*.

```
<a href=";">null-link-3</a>
```

The next alternative when clicked, when clicked, moves to document start - *not a null link*.

```
<a href="" onclick="javascript:;">null-link-4</a>
```

**Now, here are the ones that worked : True Null Links:**

Both of the alternatives below, when clicked, do strictly nothing - *null links? YES*.

```
<a href="" onclick="return false;">null-link-5</a>
```

This other one is almost the same as the above, but is offered as a true alternative, mostly for its brevity.

```
<a href="" onclick="return !1;">null-link-6</a>
```

**NOTE:** One of the key differences between my working solutions and those of **nnnnnn**, is my preference of a blank `href`, otherwise, they work on the very same principle.

Comment: What is the difference between `return false;` and `return !1;` ?

Comment: @CeylanMumunKocabaş perhaps the difference is in expression, but they evaluate to the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

Wikipedia uses the third option. To use that, you can use this HTML:

```
<a href="#">link</a>
```

And then attach an event handler with JavaScript:

```
// I assume `link` is set the element shown above.
link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    alert("You clicked me!");
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}, false);
```

`addEventListener` should work in most modern browsers, but to be more compatible and more concise, you may wish to use a JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/):

```
$("a").click(function() {
    alert("You clicked me!");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Different methods to make a null link.

```
<a href="#!">Example link</a>
```

OR

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">Example link</a>
```

Comment: PLlease format your code properly - especially when you're using HTML or other tag-based languages. Otherwise it gets formatted as a part of the page, and your answer ends up looking like it isn't one

Answer (score -5):

I think you could do well by leaving the href empty altogether, this will show the link to current page :

```
<a href="" >Example</a>
```

Comment: Will cause page reload in some older browsers, IIRC.

Comment: Well in that case, he will definitely have to write some script.