# Prevent angular 2 from redirecting <a href="#"> to homepage

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I have a sample login page which directs to a dashboard. The login page is set as the initial redirect page and this routes to the dashboard. The dashboard contains a dropdown menu with some  links. Everytime a link is clicked it keeps redirecting to the login page. However, when the dashboard page is reloaded the dropdown menu works completely fine.

I am thinking of using the "event.preventDefault()" for the links but I hope there is a workaround.

**Dashboard Menu - HTML**

```
<div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
  <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"></i> Manage Events<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
</div>
```

**Edit:** After getting some replies, I would like to clarify my main problem.The problem exists in the link being a null link and that Angular 2 takes it as a null link and causes it to redirect it. If I could find a workaround to tell Angular, don't take this link as a null link it will be ideal.

Comment: Try the following code `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return false;" ngclick="Your function()">`

Comment: @AniketV Hi, thanks for the reply, but it still proceeds to redirect to the homepage.

Comment: Put your code please

Comment: Please share your dashboard menu code. Looks like you have a form on the dashboard that is probably getting auto submitted.

Comment: I have added the dashboard menu HTML code. If there is anything more I should add do let me know.

Comment: @IsiraK did you find a solution to this

Comment: @FourtyTwo Unfortunately not. It may have been updated in the newer Angular versions which I have not touched yet.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want any redirection when clicking on your link(s), check out these solutions:

[Different methods to make a null link?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29369345/5915205)

Or you can put `<a>` tag without `href` attribute.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried removing the href attribute in the link. It proceeds to be unclickable and not expand the menu though.

Comment: This doesn't work. Removing `href=#` makes the element unclickable

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="javascript: void(0);"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"></i> Manage Events<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
          <li>
            <a [routerLink]="['ManageEvents/LoremIpsum']">Lorem Ipsum</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a [routerLink]="['ManageEvents/LoremIpsum']>Lorem Ipsum</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

`export const routes: Routes = [

    { path: 'ManageEvents/LoremIpsum', component: ManageEventsLoremIpsum }
];`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I did try the "javascript: void(0);" but it made the link unclickable.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me!!

```
<a href="" onclick="return false;">link</a>
```

hope this helps link also working by this way

Answer (score 3):

For me I used the `routerLink` and set it to empty:

```
<a [routerLink]="" (click)="onClickPage()">Click me</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to remove href, setting `cursor: pointer` with css and handle click on th `a` element like `<a (click)=yourFunction()></a>`. it should work ;)

Answer (score 1):

For me it **javascript:void(0);** works. Angular 14

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"> Last Page </a> // HTML file
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use `<a href>Lorem Ipsum</a>`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The problem is still there though.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. I've also added ng-click to the a-tag, but I don't think that it'll make a difference. Sorry to hear that this solution doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation after parent received events from child component, it redirect to homepage. I solved the problem in parent

`receiveMessage($event) { //do something this.router.navigateByUrl('/parent-route'); }`

even the parent route are supposed to accept parameters.